# In Symfony, how to match a specific route regex?

Tags: regex, symfony, routes, attributes

My question is very basic but I cannot find the answer.
Could you give me an example url to match this route?

```
#[Route('/blog/{post/<[0-9]+>}', name:'view_blog_post')]
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html) ? Because it is well explained [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#route-parameters).

Comment: Yes, I read the documentation but this case is not described with a slash inside the slug parameter and "<", ">"

Comment: I missed that part. Why is there a `/` here ? I don't think you can have matching paths with that. It does not match the [regex](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.4/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Route.php#L419)